# Separate a float into 4 uint8_ts and then merge back together

Tags: c++, c, casting

I'm working on developing both the client(C) and server(C++) side of an RF connection. I need to send a float value, but the way the architecture is set up I have to arrange my message in a struct that limits me to 3 uint8t parameters: p0, p1, p2.  My solution was to break the float into an array of 4 uint8_ts and send in 2 separate messages and use p0 as an identifier whether the message contains the first or second half.

So far I have something like this:

Server (C++):

```cpp
sendFloat(float f)
{
   messageStruct msg1, msg2;
   uint8_t* array = (uint8_t*)(&f);

   msg1.p0 = 1; //1 means it's the first half
   msg1.p1 = array[0];
   msg1.p2 = array[1];

   msg2.p0 = 0; //0 means it's the second half
   msg2.p1 = array[2];
   msg2.p2 = array[3];

   sendOverRf(msg1);
   sendOverRf(msg2);
}
```

Client(C):

```cpp
processReceivedMessage (uint32_t id, uint32_t byteA, uint32_t byteB) //(p0,p1,p2) are routed here
{
   static uint32_t firsHalfOfFloat;
   uint32_t ondHalfOfFloat;
   float combinedFloat;
   
   if(id == 1) //first half
   {
       firstHalfOfFloat = (byteA << 8) | byteB;
   }
   else        //second half
   {
       secondHalfOfFloat = (byteA << 8) | byteB;
       combinedFloat = (float)((firstHalfOfFloat << 16) | secondHalfOfFloat);
   }
  
    writeFloatToFile(combinedFloat);
}
```

then on request the client must then send that float back

Client(C):

```cpp
sendFloatBack(uint8_t firstHalfIdentifier) // is commanded twice by server with both 0 and 1 ids
{
    messageStruct msg;
    float f = getFloatFromFile();
    uint8_t* array = (uint8_t*)(&f);
    
    msg.p0 = firstHalfIdentifier;

    if(firstHalfIdentifier == 1) //First half
    {
        msg.p1 = array[0];
        msg.p2 = array[1];       
    }
    else                         //Second half
    {
        msg.p1 = array[2];
        msg.p2 = array[3];  
    }
    
    sendOverRf(msg);
}
```

and finally the Server (C++) gets the value back:

```cpp
retrieveFunc()
{
    float f;
    uint32_t firstHalf;
    uint32_t secondHalf;
        
    messageStruct msg = recieveOverRf();
    firstHalf = (msg.p1 << 8) | msg.p2;
    msg = receiveOverRf();
    firstHalf = (msg.p1 << 8) | msg.p2;
    f = (firstHalf << 16) | secondHalf;  
}
```

but I'm getting really wrong values back. Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you checked the individual bytes at each step to see if they match what you expect?

Comment: Yes I think my problem is how I'm putting the float back together on retrieval

Comment: endianness the same on both ends? it matters for floats too

Comment: its odd that you choose different methods for splitting and reassembling. I would chose the same

Comment: Think about this `f = (firstHalf << 16) | secondHalf;`. What type do you think the expression on the right side of the `=` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unions are a very convenient way to disassemble a `float` into individual bytes and later put the bytes back together again.  Here's some example code showing how you can do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union {
   uint8_t _asBytes[4];
   float   _asFloat;
} FloatBytesConverter;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FloatBytesConverter fbc;
    fbc._asFloat = 3.14159;

    printf("Original float value is:  %f\n", fbc._asFloat);

    printf("The bytes of the float are:  %u, %u, %u, %u\n"
       , fbc._asBytes[0]
       , fbc._asBytes[1]
       , fbc._asBytes[2]
       , fbc._asBytes[3]);

    // Now let's put the float back together from the individual bytes
    FloatBytesConverter ac;
    ac._asBytes[0] = fbc._asBytes[0];
    ac._asBytes[1] = fbc._asBytes[1];
    ac._asBytes[2] = fbc._asBytes[2];
    ac._asBytes[3] = fbc._asBytes[3];

    printf("Restored float is %f\n", ac._asFloat);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So damn clean I love it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

memcpy is your friend.

```
float toFloat(const uint8_t *arr)
{
    float result;

    memcpy(&result, arr, sizeof(result));

    return result;
}

uint8_t *toArray(const float x, uint8_t * const arr)
{
    memcpy(arr, &x, sizeof(x));
    return arr;
}
```

```
void sendFloat(float f)
{
   messageStruct msg1, msg2;
   uint8_t array[4];

   toArray(f, array);

   msg1.p0 = 1; //1 means it's the first half
   msg1.p1 = array[0];
   msg1.p2 = array[1];

   msg2.p0 = 0; //0 means it's the second half
   msg2.p1 = array[2];
   msg2.p2 = array[3];

   sendOverRf(msg1);
   sendOverRf(msg2);
}
```

```
float retrieveFunc(void)
{
    float f;
    unit8_t array[4]
        
    messageStruct msg = recieveOverRf();
    array[0] = msg.p1;
    array[1] = msg.p2;
    msg = receiveOverRf();
    array[2] = msg.p1;
    array[3] = msg.p2;
    return toFloat(array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, bytes are bytes as far as architectures are concerned.

We assume that we're using IEEE 754 (or whatever) on both sides.

We can put one `float` (4 bytes) into/outof one `uint32_t` with `memcpy`

But, we have to deal with processor endianness.

**Edit:**

> problem with this is that p0, p1, p2 are all uint8_ts. – 
> TheBigJabronie

Oops, my bad. I've updated the code to use only bytes [I've left my original/incorrect answer below for reference].

---

Here is the updated code. The functions will work on either host, regardless of the endianness of each architecture.

Note that your main issue is the encoding of the `float`. So, the code below assumes that the packets arrive intact (i.e. retry/resend is done in the lower RF layer)

```
void
sendFloat(float f)
{
    messageStruct msg;
    uint32_t i32;

    assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t));

    // get bytes of the float in native endian order
    memcpy(&i32,&f,sizeof(i32));

    // handle endianness
    i32 = htonl(i32);

    // send MSW half
    msg.p0 = 1;
    msg.p1 = i32 >> 24;
    msg.p2 = i32 >> 16;
    sendOverRf(msg);

    // send LSW half
    msg.p0 = 2;
    msg.p1 = i32 >> 8;
    msg.p2 = i32 >> 0;
    sendOverRf(msg);
}

float
recvFloat(void)
{
    uint32_t i32 = 0;
    float f;

    messageStruct msg;

    // NOTE: the two packets _should_ come in the same order as the sender, but
    // we'll handle out of order packets to be complete
    for (int rcount = 0;  rcount < 2;  ++rcount) {
        msg = recieveOverRf();

        uint32_t tmp = msg.p1;
        tmp <<= 8;
        tmp |= msg.p2;

        switch (msg.p0) {
        case 1:
            i32 |= tmp << 16;
            break;
        case 2:
            i32 |= tmp << 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    // handle endianness
    i32 = ntohl(i32);

    // get bytes into float
    memcpy(&f,&i32,sizeof(float));

    return f;
}
```

---

My original code and further assumptions.

We can do this in a *single* message with room to spare.

Here is the code I would use.

```
void
sendFloat(float f)
{
    messageStruct msg;
    uint32_t i32;

    assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t));

    // get bytes of the float in native endian order
    memcpy(&i32,&f,sizeof(i32));

    // handle endianness
    i32 = htonl(i32);

    // means we're sending a float
    msg.p0 = CMD_FLOAT;
    msg.p1 = i32;
    msg.p2 = 0;

    sendOverRf(msg);
}

float
recvFloat(void)
{
    uint32_t i32;
    float f;

    messageStruct msg = recieveOverRf();

    // ensure we got correct message
    if (msg.p0 != CMD_FLOAT)
        exit(1);

    // get int in network order
    i32 = msg.p1;

    // handle endianness
    i32 = ntohl(i32);

    // get bytes into float
    memcpy(&f,&i32,sizeof(float));

    return f;
}
```

Comment: problem with this is that p0, p1, p2 are all uint8_ts.